# How to find out the correct query in laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have a query in my controller.

```
$results = DB::table('zaiko')
               ->where('soukobango',$souko_bango_for_joining)
               ->join('syouhin1','zaiko.syouhinbango','=','syouhin1.bango')
               ->where('syouhin1.isphoto','is distinct from','1')
               ->select(DB::raw("syouhin1.bango,
                  syouhin1.kokyakusyouhinbango,
                  syouhin1.jouhou,
                  syouhin1.tokuchou,
                  zaiko.tanabango,
                  SPLIT_PART(zaiko.datachar02, '|', 1) AS lot_no"))
```

This is working ok. Now, I want to get some `$special_result` from `$results`. I want to match the existing result with two arrays and get that result.

```
$special_syouhin_bangos = [10,11];
$special_tana_bangos = ["MIKAKUTEI","TANA01"];

$special_syouhins = $results->wherein('syouhin1.bango',$special_syouhin_bangos)
                            ->wherein('zaiko.tanabango',$special_tana_bangos)->get();
```

What I am getting is like below,

```
+--------------+-----------+
| syouhinbango | tanabango |
+--------------+-----------+
| 10           | MIKAKUTEI |
+--------------+-----------+
| 11           | MIKAKUTEI |
+--------------+-----------+
| 11           | TANA01    |
+--------------+-----------+
```

What I want is like below,

```
+--------------+-----------+
| syouhinbango | tanabango |
+--------------+-----------+
| 10           | MIKAKUTEI |
+--------------+-----------+
| 11           | TANA01    |
+--------------+-----------+
```

What I want is match the first element of `$special_syouhin_bangos`(10) with first element of `$special_tana_bangos`(MIKAKUTEI) and get one row of that. Then I want to match the second elements of both array and get another row as result. This way I want to get the `$special_results`. It is guaranteed that both `$special_syouhin_bangos` and `$special_tana_bangos` will have same number of elements.

I feel like I need to run a loop. But I still can't quite work it out.

Comment: You may want to use `DISTINCT` in your query? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$special_syouhins = $results->wherein('syouhin1.bango',$special_syouhin_bangos)
                        ->wherein('zaiko.tanabango',$special_tana_bangos)->get();
```

with

```
$special_syouhins = $results->wherein('syouhin1.bango',$special_syouhin_bangos)
                        ->wherein('zaiko.tanabango',$special_tana_bangos)->distinct()->get();
```